# Dragon Naturally Speaking Professional 12.5 speech is slow

Tags: windows-7

when a user attempts to use Dragon Naturally Speaking Professional 12.5 by speaking into the microphone, the words displayed on screen is very slow. we assume it might be memory related but it still translate spoken words into MS Word very slow. Help?

Comment: If you suspect its a memory problem then you should add more memory to the system in question.

Answer (score 0):

Start the Task Manager by searching Task Manager or right clicking Task Bar and Launching Task Manager.

Click on the performance tab and then view the RAM and CPU use while you are using Dragon.

If it is memory, you will see quickly and then an upgrade is simple.  If it is CPU bound, then it could be more of a challenge.

Clicking on the processes tab and looking at CPU and memory use would also point you to apps that are using CPU and RAM. Clicking on the CPU or Memory column header will sort that column High to Low or Low to High

You can also look to disable any running processes that are not needed to see if that helps.  Starting System Configuration and looking at processes and applications that run at Startup(Startup Tab) will allow you to temporarily disable things so you can test impact.